# Best practice for marking CharFields for translation in django models?

Tags: django, internationalization, translation, gettext

I have a few models for which a specific `CharField` has to be systematically translated.

It appears that those are never picked-up by `compilemessages`, but are translated ok when the translation is manually introduced into the `.po` file.

Of course it creates an issue each time I update the `.po` files... which led me several time to loose those specific translation without realizing

I therefore wanted to mark those specific `CharField` for translation once and for all.

I was first expecting a declaration in the `CharField` definition such as:

```
label = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='empty', unique=True, mark_for_translation=True)
```

but looking for it on the documentation, then directly in the Django code ... such a functionality is not currently implemented

Then I tried within my code to mark it with `gettext_noop`, but apparently, in the following code, the corresponding messages are not picked-up during the `compilemessages` instruction.

```
def difficulty_label_from_index():
    difficulties = Difficulty.objects.all().values("label", "index")
    # Translators: PuzzleDifficulty label
    return {diff['index']: gettext_noop(diff['label']) for diff in difficulties}
```

Does anyone has a clue why it is not working?

or what could be best practices when we need to mark content of a `CharField` for translation?